# Xcode static table generator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

[image: title]

I have a project that utilizes static table. However, I found it unbelievably tedious to entering view by view. Is there a generator or some sort that I can use to create a storyboard like this?

By the way, I have already tried the dynamic prototype table. I have to write a lot of `if(cell == 'Head of School')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your tables from code. Use one TableViewController as base class and init is with different datasources. Try looking at [NimbusKit](http://nimbuskit.info/) Tables. This is pretty easy. And it allows to create static tables with few lines of code.